# Rails crashes on SQL update overflow

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've run into a bit of a strange problem working on a project.

This occurs specifically on the "show" action of my ClientsController. Basically, the behavior I want is that any time a user checks out a specific client page it updates the record of the last client page visited if its a different page. However, when the "show" action is run its currently causing the server to run into a SQL update loop until it crashes.

There are two models involved: User and Client. The two models have a "has_and_belongs_to_many" association. Here's the related controller code:

**ClientsController**

```
def show
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  check_last_client(@client)
end

def check_last_client(client)
  if client.id != current_user.last_client
    current_user.last_client = client.id
    current_user.save
  end
end
```

And here's the gist of the server log:

```
Processing by ClientsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 9  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

(0.1ms)  begin transaction

SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_client" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 9  [["last_client", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-08-26 22:12:40.695487"]]
SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_client" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 9  [["last_client", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-08-26 22:12:40.695487"]]
SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_client" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 9  [["last_client", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-08-26 22:12:40.695487"]]
Illegal Transaction: 4
```

It seems like a relatively straightforward update to me, then again maybe I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your `Client` model have any callbacks?

Comment: No but User does, specifically there's an after_save callback to make sure self.last_client is set. I was thinking this could be the cause as I was walking home today. Will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Please update the question with the User after_save callback code

Comment: That sounds like you've got an infinite loop going on (callback triggering another save, callback runs again etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something like this in your `User` `after_save` callback:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :ensure_last_client

  def ensure_last_client
    # This triggers an infinite loop
    update(last_client: last_client || 1)
  end
end
```

As [the Rails documentation explains](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), the `after_save` callback is called during the process of calling `save` on the record. So if your callback triggers another call to `save` on the same instance, you'll get in an infinite loop of persistence craziness. In your logs you can see this as well, as the transaction is started but never ended.

The fix is straightforward, make sure you never call `save`, `update` or `update_attributes` on the same instance. You could instead ensure `last_client` is set in a `before_save` callback:

```
before_save :ensure_last_client

def ensure_last_client
  # This only sets the attribute, but doesn't save it
  write_attribute(:last_client, last_client || 1)
end
```

Now the attribute is set, but not yet written to the database. At a later point in the persistence cycle, it is actually updated or inserted into the database, so you don't have to explicitly call `save`.

### Bonus: Skinny Controller

This is a recommendation, and not necessarily a required part of the answer.

In your controller, you have the method `check_last_client`, which sets the last client on a user and then saves it. Since the method is about updating the internal state of the user, it would be more logical to move this logic into `User`, and providing a single method the controller can call:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other logic

  def check_last_client(client)
    return if client.id == last_client

    update(last_client: client.id)
  end
end
```

Then your controller becomes much cleaner and doesn't need to know exactly how the last client should be updated and under which conditions. It can just fire off a single call:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])

    current_user.check_last_client(@client)
  end
end
```

Comment: I realized I had never given credit where credit was due. Thanks for the well formatted, informative answer. Because of specifics of how information needs to be processed, the stack overflow solution needed to be a little different (after_create as opposed to a before_ callback) but you're comments were spot on. Also, very much appreciate the Controller comments. I was already considering moving the logic to the model as I hate bloated controllers, and your comments made for a much cleaner concise fix.